# label having sizeToFits() goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a tableview in where each cell has a label. The datasource of this label is from the firebase api. Now, initially the label is loaded in a perfect form. As you scroll through and if any label is of a shorter text  width, the rest of the cell, alter their labels to this size.

I even tried applying a stackview around it, but i couldn't help much

Below is the code of `cellForRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as? FeedCell {

        cell.caption.text = ""
        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        cell.caption.sizeToFit()
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    } else {
        return FeedCell()
    }
}
```

code for function in TableviewCell

```
func configureCell(post: Posts, img: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.posts = post
    self.caption.text = posts.caption
}
```

I am really unable to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20043138/442121 You should uncheck use Autolayout or try another answer is working for you

Comment: thanks thats a great fix. But I already have a app in production. Removing auto layout means resizing most of the things. I tried it. Many things just went completely wrong visually. Is there any other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using auto-layout to set a minimum width in percentage of a screen size IOS.
Auto-Layout constraint has that multiplier parameter that lets you use a fractional relationship between a superview and its subview.

> While both the child view (***Label***) and its superview are selected, add "equal width". Then change the "multiplier" of the constraint you just added to the proportion you need. For example, for 30%

Comment: Many Thanks for the response. I’ll update you on this.